# Electricity vs Current

Tags: electricity, electric-current, definition

**BACKGROUND:** Electromagnetism has been the hardest concept in physics that I do not understand at all back in my old school. Now, I just started studying robotics which requires the basic understanding of electricity.

I have a hard time differentiating electricity and current when defining them. Are both of them the flow of electrons or is electricity an umbrella term that happens to include current?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Posj4WMo0o at 0:24 it stated that "To use electricity, we need electrons to flow in the same direction around the circuit.", does this imply that electricity is a product of current? And would that be enough in defining electricity or is it something more?

How exactly are they different when observed in an atomic level?

I asked my teacher about this matter and she stated that electricity is the flow of electrons while electrical current is a stream of charged particles (like electrons). The definition she gave doesn't really help.

Comment: It seems like this is an English language question regarding the colloquial meaning of the words "Electricity" vs "current", not a well-defined physics question.

Comment: Apologies for that. I have a hard time understanding and differentiating both electricity and current on an atomic (?) level.

Comment: A power plant generator is an example of electricity; in the generator it produces a current.  Just like a lever is an example of mechanics; the lever has forces at each end.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly the descriptions of the 2 tags you used are as follows:

Electricity:  The study of the presence and flow of electric charge. Charges, currents, fields, potentials.

Electric Current: A measure of the rate at which electric charge is transported (especially
through a circuit), it has units of charge/time.

Electricity is more of a generic term, depending on context, the word may refer to electric charge, power or energy. While electric current is specifically measure of the rate at which electric charge is transported.

Comment: Would you be able to expand more on their nuances? I'm still kind of confused.

Comment: Electricity is more of a generic term, depending on context, the word may refer to electric charge, power or energy. While electric current is specifically measure of the rate at which electric charge is transported.

Answer (score 1):

"Electricity" is a general term for applications using the electrical force, such as electrical circuits, electrical motors, electrical generators, etc.  "Current" is one characteristic of electricity, as is electromotive force,  voltage, resistance, capacitance, inductance, etc.

This is similar to "Mechanics" as a general term for the the motion of objects subject to forces in general, including such characteristics as inertia, torques, momentum, etc.  Or "Thermodynamics" as the general term that includes such characteristics as heat, work, internal energy, entropy, etc.

"Electricity" is a part of "Electromagnetics", a much broader term that in addition to electricity includes electromagnetic waves.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this actually helped clarify certain things for me! But can you expand more on the concept of electrical force?

Comment: Electrical force is the force between charged particles, one of the fundamental forces; the force of gravity between masses is another fundamental force.  (There are four known fundamental forces: electromagnetic, gravity, strong nuclear, and weak nuclear.)  See a physics text, such as one by Halliday and Resnick.

Comment: In a circuit, a source of electromotive force- battery or generator for example- causes a separation of negative and positive charges; the similarly charged particles- such as the electrons at the negative terminal of a battery- flow as a current away from the negative terminal- due their common repulsion from the electrical force- through the circuit to the positive terminal of the battery .

Answer (score 0):

"Electricity" is a colloquial word in English used variously to describe things like electric charge, current, and so on. Whereas, "Current" or "Electric current" has a more precise definition in physics and is related to time rate of change of charge. You do not need to be able to precisely differentiate between "Electricity" and "Current" in order to understand electromagnetism.

To learn about electromagnetism I think it would be better to avoid YouTube videos and rather consult a reputable physics textbook.

Comment: So electricity is more of an umbrella or general term right? And current is NOT the act of electrons moving but rather refers to the rate/speed or how fast it moves?

Comment: Also, if we were to use the water analogy; if current would be the flow of the water, what should electricity be in this case?

Comment: Current (i) is the derivative of charge (q) with respect to time (t). In symbols: i=dq/dt

Comment: "Electricity" is, like I said, colloquial. I guess in the water analogy you could say it is either water, or the flow of water, or wetness, or whatever you want.